# lipsing or liping

Tags: meaning, verbs, adjectives, adverbs

As I am learning english, I wanted to write a comment on a particular post. in that post, there is a girl sings a song while the song itself is getting played on the CD. so, is it correct to describe that situation as "perfect timed lipsing" Or "perfect timed liping"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word you are looking for is "lip syncing", sometimes written "lipsyncing" or "lip-syncing".   Alternatively you could say "[lip sync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lip_sync)" to describe the general process, which I'm guessing is what you misheard to get "lipsing".
a
Wikipedia

Comment: Thank you..but i have a nother small question please....which is correct of the following sentences "..it was an electrifying match" OR "...it was an electric match"

Comment: @Elpharaoh check the dictionary - the adjective definition meaning "thrilling" http://www.thefreedictionary.com/electrifying